# How specific CommandParameter in xaml to know type of object

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, icommand

I use iCommand in my project. I've got a window with buttons. Every button contain Image with category of clothes and every category has it own class. After click on button I need to know type of category  in parameter. Is there any solution for my problem?

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
<i:EventTrigger EventName="HandCursorClick">
<i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MyCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ????}"/>
</i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

I can bind Image, but it isn't giving me proper answer about type of object which represents that image...

In BehindCode I've got:

```
public ICommand MyCommand
        {
           get { return _myCommand ?? (_myCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(CategoryExecuted)); }
        }

public void CategoryExecuted(object parameter)
        {
           Shoes s = parameter as Shoes;
           if(s!=null)
           {
           ....
           }
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure the **CategoryExecuted()** method being called? If so, what is the object type that is being passed in?

Comment: Yes, it being called. I've got Breakpoint in CategoryExecuted and debugger stop at it. But parameter is null and I can't check type.

Comment: Your example has "{Binding ????}" for your CommandParameter. What are you using in your code to hit your breakpoint? Are you binding to something on your viewmodel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have lat's say Category_1 property in your view model 
you can bind to it in the command parameter in the Button of category1
to usethe binding 
the key is to have the property in your view model 
`<i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MyCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Category_1}"/>`